# Como generar un .exe de un archivo .py que usa dependencias

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, exe, spyder

He intentado generar un ejecutable de mi archivo "main.py" pero en si este script manda a llamar a otros scrpits, he visto que se puede modificar el archivo ".spec" que crea pyinstaller pero no se como modificarlo para que use esos arhivos ".py" de los cual depende "main.py". Al final lo que me arroja al ejecutar el exe es esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No has añadido la librería de PyQt5 en tu archivo generado. Lo pone ahí muy claro, en la linea encima de la que has subrayado. Diviertete leyendo: https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/packaging-and-distribution/packaging-pyqt5-pyside2-applications-windows-pyinstaller/

Comment: Eso es lo que no entiendo, si tengo importada la librería en mi archivo ".py" por eso no se de que forma generarlo correctamente